# warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, pointers, warnings

I want to Prompt the user to enter 3 numbers. Then, swap the first number with the second one, the second number with the third and the third with the first by calling a function called "swap".

Functions in `C` cannot return more than one value so I decided to create a structure with pointers that I will later use in my function. Then, I created three-pointers that will store the address of each one of the numbers so I can dereference to these numbers in my function (as shown below)

```
Number.pa = *ppb;
Number.pb = *ppc;
Number.pc = *ppa;
```

**Here's my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(); // a = b, b = c, c = a

struct Numbers {

    int *pa, *pb, *pc;

} ;

int main(void) {

    struct Numbers Number; // Structure to hold the values of the three variables.

    int a, b, c;
    int *ppa, *ppb, *ppc;                                              
    printf("\n Please enter three integer numbers: ");  
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    ppa = &a; ppb = &b; ppc = &c;                                         
    swap(a, b, c, Number, *ppa, *ppb, *ppc);
    printf("\n %d \t %d \t %d \n", Number.pa, Number.pb, Number.pc);
}

void swap(int a, int b, int c, struct Numbers Number, int *ppa, int *ppb, int *ppc) { 

    Number.pa = *ppb;
    Number.pb = *ppc;
    Number.pc = *ppa;  

   } ;
```

Comment: regarding this function prototype: `void swap();`  This does not match the signature of the actual function.  Amongst other other problems, the compiler will assume (in the actual function) that all the parameters are of type `int`

Comment: regarding: `void swap(int a, int b, int c, struct Numbers Number, int *ppa, int *ppb, int *ppc) {`  The compiler will output a warning message about unused parameters for the first 3 parameters.  Suggest removing those 3 parameters.  Also this parameter: `struct Numbers Number,` would be better written as `struct Numbers *Number`  And it is a poor programming practice to use the same name for a parameter as the name of the struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the arguments to your swap function are either pointless or the work of sheer guessing (or both). The assignment effectively wants you to "rotate" values from `a` through `c`. So do that, and *only* that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *pa, int *pb, int *pc);

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c;

    printf("\n Please enter three integer numbers: ");  
    if (scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
    {
        swap(&a, &b, &c);
        printf("%d %d %d \n", a, b, c);
    }
    return 0;
}

void swap(int *pa, int *pb, int *pc)
{ 
    int tmp = *pa;
    *pa = *pb;
    *pb = *pc;
    *pc = tmp;
}
```

Stop reading more into an assignment than is there. If it sounds simple, it probably is. The warning was due to passing the value of dereferenced pointers to `int` (so `int` values) to a function expecting `int` pointers; not `int` values. As you can see, you don't need to do any of that (and didn't in the first place).

Comment: I understand the process of your work and the implementation of the code but I can't understand this statement: if (scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) == 3) and what it does.

Comment: suggest reading the MAN page for `scanf()`, especially the section named: `RETURN VALUE``